# Google Authenticator FreeRADIUS

Tags: redhat, pam, radius, freeradius, google-authenticator

I'm trying to implement google authenticator PAM module in FreeRADIUS on RHEL7.

I've loosely followed this guide: http://www.supertechguy.com/help/security/freeradius-google-auth

The reason I say loosely is things appear to have changed with the google module recently so I have built it by performing:

```
sudo yum -y install freeradius freeradius-utils git gcc pam-devel qrencode qrencode-libs qrencode-devel git autoconf automake libtool freeradius-mysql
git clone https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam
Cd google-authenticator-libpam
sudo ./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This all worked ok. I've then configured the configuration files using the guide. My /etc/pam.d/radiusd file looks like this:

```
#%PAM-1.0
#auth       include     password-auth
#account    required    pam_nologin.so
#account    include     password-auth
#password   include     password-auth
#session    include     password-auth
auth requisite pam_google_authenticator.so forward_pass
#auth required pam_unix.so use_first_pass
account required pam_permit.so
session required pam_permit.so
```

Everything runs ok but when I attempt to test it I get rejected everytime. I've ran radiusd -X and get the following output when attempting to connect:

```
    Received Access-Request Id 168 from 127.0.0.1:48534 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 77
        User-Name = 'username'
        User-Password = 'Password'
        NAS-IP-Address = 10.133.16.125
        NAS-Port = 18120
        Message-Authenticator = 0x7ba3ce64279bce1f09a978dd7204ec3f
(0) Received Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 48534, id=168, length=77
(0)     User-Name = 'username'
(0)     User-Password = 'Password'
(0)     NAS-IP-Address = 10.133.16.125
(0)     NAS-Port = 18120
(0)     Message-Authenticator = 0x7ba3ce64279bce1f09a978dd7204ec3f
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)   filter_username filter_username {
(0)     if (!&User-Name)
(0)     if (!&User-Name)  -> FALSE
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ / /)
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /@.*@/ )
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /@.*@/ )  -> FALSE
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.\\./ )
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.\\./ )  -> FALSE
(0)     if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\\.(.+)$/))
(0)     if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.$/)
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.$/)   -> FALSE
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /@\\./)
(0)     if (&User-Name =~ /@\\./)   -> FALSE
(0)   } # filter_username filter_username = notfound
(0)   [preprocess] = ok
(0)   [chap] = noop
(0)   [mschap] = noop
(0)   [digest] = noop
(0)  suffix : Checking for suffix after "@"
(0)  suffix : No '@' in User-Name = "username", looking up realm NULL
(0)  suffix : No such realm "NULL"
(0)   [suffix] = noop
(0)  eap : No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(0)   [eap] = noop
(0)  files : users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 187
(0)   [files] = ok
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (4)
(0)  sql : User not found in any groups
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (4)
rlm_sql (sql): Closing connection (0), from 1 unused connections
rlm_sql (sql): Closing connection (3): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 540 seconds
rlm_sql (sql): You probably need to lower "min"
rlm_sql (sql): Closing connection (2): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 540 seconds
rlm_sql (sql): You probably need to lower "min"
rlm_sql (sql): Closing connection (1): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 540 seconds
rlm_sql (sql): You probably need to lower "min"
(0)   [sql] = notfound
(0)   [expiration] = noop
(0)   [logintime] = noop
(0)  WARNING: pap : No "known good" password found for the user.  Not setting Auth-Type
(0)  WARNING: pap : Authentication will fail unless a "known good" password is available
(0)   [pap] = noop
(0)  } #  authorize = ok
(0) Found Auth-Type = PAM
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authenticate {
pam_pass: using pamauth string <radiusd> for pam.conf lookup
pam_pass: function pam_authenticate FAILED for <username>. Reason: Module is unknown
(0)   [pam] = reject
(0)  } #  authenticate = reject
(0) Failed to authenticate the user
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)  Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(0)   [sql] = noop
(0)  attr_filter.access_reject : EXPAND %{User-Name}
(0)  attr_filter.access_reject :    --> username
(0)  attr_filter.access_reject : Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(0)   [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(0)  eap : Request didn't contain an EAP-Message, not inserting EAP-Failure
(0)   [eap] = noop
(0)   remove_reply_message_if_eap remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)     if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)
(0)     if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)    else else {
(0)     [noop] = noop
(0)    } # else else = noop
(0)   } # remove_reply_message_if_eap remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)  } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(0) Delaying response for 1 seconds
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Waking up in 0.6 seconds.
(0) Sending delayed response
(0) Sending Access-Reject packet to host 127.0.0.1 port 48534, id=168, length=0
Sending Access-Reject Id 168 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:48534
Waking up in 3.9 seconds.
(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 168 with timestamp +540
Ready to process requests
```

(sorry about the long output). The lines that confuse me are:

```
pam_pass: using pamauth string <radiusd> for pam.conf lookup
pam_pass: function pam_authenticate FAILED for <username>. Reason: Module is unknown
```

If I search for the file I get returned:

```
[ ~]$ sudo find / -name "pam_google_authenticator.so"
/usr/local/lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so
/home//google-authenticator-libpam/.libs/pam_google_authenticator.so
[ ~]$
```

and I believe /usr/local/lib/security is the right place but I can't comment 100% on that one.

Anyone have any ideas or advice where I can look next or if I am missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (or rather, someone pointed out the obvious)

Changed the line in /etc/pam.d/radiusd from:

```
auth requisite pam_google_authenticator.so forward_pass
```

to

```
auth requisite /usr/local/lib/security/pam_google_authenticator.so forward_pass
```

This then found the module and worked correctly.